# Could not load content for webpack:///src/app/carrier/create-load/create-load.component.ts (HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME)

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. suddenly my .ts file stopped open in chrome devtools. It is giving error

> Could not load content for
>   webpack:///src/app/carrier/create-load/create-load.component.ts (HTTP
>   error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME).

[image]

I am using lazy loading in my project.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did it ever work? Please, show the code of your component.

Comment: Hi @Lynx242, Yes. It was working till yesterday morning. My component code is not fitting in this edit box. Can you tell me how can I share my code?

Comment: You can edit your question and put it underneath your text. there ain't no limit.

Comment: try restarting `ng serve`